# Converting HSB color to RGB in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, colors

I'm trying to convert HSB values to RGB values using [this algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5590028/458960), but I am not getting correct values. I have a fixed s of 29, a fixed b of 100, and am generating random integers between 0-360 for the h value, and feeding them into the function to get RGB back:

[image]

```
float h = (arc4random() % 360);
float s = 29;
float b = 100;
HSL2RGB(h, s, b, &red, &green, &blue);
NSLog(@"r:%f g:%f b:%f", red, green, blue);
```

output:

```
r:2971.000000 g:2971.000000 b:2971.000000
```

I tried this too:

```
float h = (arc4random() % 360)/1000.0;
float s = 0.29;
float b = 1.0;
HSL2RGB(h, s, b, &red, &green, &blue);
NSLog(@"r:%f g:%f b:%f", red, green, blue);
```

output:

`r:1.000000 g:1.000000 b:1.000000`

Am I doing something wrong, or is this algorithm messed up?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with [`+[UIColor colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:)?

Comment: Wow. I've been searching for hours for a good algorithm, and I had this all along :(

Comment: Though I don't get how they want hue to be a value from 0 - 1 when I have it in degrees from 0 - 360. How would I convert that?

Comment: 0 is 0, 1 is 360. Just as with RGB colors. 0 is 0, 1 is 255.

Comment: I am just overcomplicating things today :/ thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know your algorithm but I should you to use this algorigthm:

```
typedef struct
{
    double r;       // percent [0 - 1]
    double g;       // percent [0 - 1]
    double b;       // percent [0 - 1]
    double a;       // percent [0 - 1]
} RGBA;

typedef struct
{
    double h;       // angle in degrees [0 - 360]
    double s;       // percent [0 - 1]
    double v;       // percent [0 - 1]
} HSV;

- (RGBA)RGBfromHSV:(HSV)value
{
    double      hh, p, q, t, ff;
    long        i;
    RGBA        out;
    out.a       = 1;

    if (value.s <= 0.0) // < is bogus, just shuts up warnings
    {       
        if (isnan(value.h)) // value.h == NAN
        {   
            out.r = value.v;
            out.g = value.v;
            out.b = value.v;
            return out;
        }

        // error - should never happen
        out.r = 0.0;
        out.g = 0.0;
        out.b = 0.0;
        return out;
    }

    hh = value.h;
    if(hh >= 360.0) hh = 0.0;
    hh /= 60.0;
    i = (long)hh;
    ff = hh - i;
    p = value.v * (1.0 - value.s);
    q = value.v * (1.0 - (value.s * ff));
    t = value.v * (1.0 - (value.s * (1.0 - ff)));

    switch(i)
    {
        case 0:
            out.r = value.v;
            out.g = t;
            out.b = p;
            break;
        case 1:
            out.r = q;
            out.g = value.v;
            out.b = p;
            break;
        case 2:
            out.r = p;
            out.g = value.v;
            out.b = t;
            break;

        case 3:
            out.r = p;
            out.g = q;
            out.b = value.v;
            break;
        case 4:
            out.r = t;
            out.g = p;
            out.b = value.v;
            break;
        case 5:
        default:
            out.r = value.v;
            out.g = p;
            out.b = q;
            break;
    }
    return out;     
}
```

I used it into own of my project and I had no problem with it. :)

Comment: What are the ranges of input values it uses? 0-360, 0-1, 0-1?

Comment: I edited the post. The range of percent values are between 0-1 and for the degree between 0-360.

Answer (score 9):

You can get the RGB components of a color constructed using HSB directly and easily using UIKit.

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue: hue saturation: saturation
                            brightness: brightness alpha: alpha];
if ( [color getRed: &red green: &green blue: &blue alpha: &alpha] ) {
    // color converted
}
```

If all you care about is using the color, you can skip the `if` and just use it.

Per Apple's [UIColor documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006892-CH3-SW47):

> If the color is in a compatible color space, the color is converted into RGB format and its components are returned to your application. If the color is not in a compatible color space, the parameters are unchanged.

A compatible color space in this case is RGB or HSB.