# HSV Color ranges table

Tags: ios, colors, rgb, uicolor, hsv

I'm developing an App in which children need to find certain colors using a certain target dot on the camera screen - kind of augmented reality like.
I've got the whole thing working already, but with RGB colors.
For each color, red, green, blue, yellow, purple, etc. I've been testing and defining the ranges of the RGB values to determine when it is exactly which color. A lot of work.

However, I've learned that using HSV it works even better. But I don't want to go through the whole process again of setting ranges for each color. But I simply can't find it anywhere online, I've been googling for two hours already!

So what I'm searching for is pretty simple:
For a set of about 8 standard colors: red, green, blue, yellow, purple, etc the corresponding HSV ranges.

For example:
The color red - 
Hue between 0 and 20, Saturation between 0.8 and 1.0, Value between 0.8 and 1.0. (not sure this is right, just an example)

I mean, someone must have done this already sometime!?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need in the ranges, but if you just need to convert between RGB and HSV, the functions in this question should do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589804/change-from-rgb-to-hsb-on-iphone

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks but I've got the conversion already. I need ranges of some standard colors, like in the example in my post

Comment: If you know the colour ranges in RGB then produce some sample data of each color in RGB, convert each one to HSV and look at the spread of new values. Then you will have your range. Once you do this for one colour you can automate the process for every other colour.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the first mathematically defined color spaces is the [CIE 1931 XYZ color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space). I think that article on Wikipedia should provide some additional insight in the complexity of what you would like to do. I am sure that someone has done this, but I don't believe it's open source.

The closest chart I found is publish on Wikipedia under [Web colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#HTML_color_names) article.
[image: CSS 1–2.0 / HTML 3.2–4 / VGA color names]

Comment: Thanks that did help me! Sorry for the late answer-tick :)

Comment: Would the HSV ranges remain the same for using openCV?