# How to count the number of pixels with a certain pixel value in python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'd like to count the number of pixels with the value=[0,100,234] in an image.

Without using loops over the image, could you please propose a method of how to determine the number of these particular pixels?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623132/calculating-the-number-of-blue-pixels-in-a-picture) answer helps.

Comment: Thanks, I checked this one already, but could not make it work with countNonzero function...

Comment: _could not make it work with countNonZero_ ... why? What's the problem?  @Namorim link is correct. You can alternatively get the length of the list returned by (something like): `np.where((image == [0, 100, 234]).all(axis = 2))`

Comment: SOrry, I dont get it...how to you proceed then to count the pixels?

Comment: Use `np.count_nonzero` replacing `np.where`.

Comment: This is one of those (many) cases in which telling us what you've tried and why those approaches didn't work for you would really be helpful. It saves a lot of people suggesting things that you've already been through and makes it easier to address the real problem.

Comment: The solution suggested by @Miki and Divakar works well! Using np.count_nonzero((img == [0, 100, 234]).all(axis = 2)) gives the number of pixels with the given colors on an image image.

Comment: Glad you make it work. Posted an answer (as Community Wiki since it's been contributed also by Divakar), so you can accept it and we can consider this question closed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To count the number of pixels with the value = `[0,100,234]` you can use:

```
np.count_nonzero((img == [0, 100, 234]).all(axis = 2))
```

Comment: `np.count_nonzero(img == value)` can be used in the grayscale case