# Return the percentage with brown pixel on image

Tags: python, opencv

I have a code where I get a video and save an images from this video every 20 frames, but I need take this images and return percentage of pixels browns whith RGB 194, 187, 138 or darker, I already did the part from, get vieo, save image, but I have no idea how return the percentage with bronws pixels

Thats my code:

```
import cv2 
import os
import numpy as np

# Read the video from specified path 
cam = cv2.VideoCapture("D:/outpy.avi") 

currentframe = 0
x = 20
while(True): 

    # reading from frame 
    ret,frame = cam.read() 

    if ret: 
        # if video is still left continue creating images 
        name = 'D:/' + str(currentframe) + '.png'
        print ('Creating...' + name) 

        # writing the extracted images
        if currentframe == x:
            cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
            imagem = cv2.imread("D:/{}.png".format(x))
            fatia = imagem[0:150, 150:300]


            x = x + 20
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

        # increasing counter so that it will 
        # show how many frames are created 
        currentframe += 1
    else: 
        break

# Release all space and windows once done 
cam.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Use the function inRange() to convert all brown pixels to white and the rest to black. Then use CountNonZero() to get the number of white pixels. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623132/calculating-the-number-of-blue-pixels-in-a-picture

Comment: ok, the inRange I use with the rgb in the code?

Comment: Yes, specify the min and max range of brown pixels for inRange. See the example I just posted in my comment.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215020/2836621

Comment: thats helps, but dont show the percentage

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
# use rgb color picker to set these based on color range you want
# (order is BGR not RGB!)
lower_brown = np.array([50, 50, 20]) # a dark brown
upper_brown = np.array([138, 187, 194]) # BGR of your brown
w,h,c = frame.shape
mask = cv2.inRange(frame, lower_brown, upper_brown)
num_brown = cv2.countNonZero(mask)
perc_brown = num_brown/float(w*h)*100
```

Could also try converting to HSV and checking the hue.

Comment: I try and return to me 2% of this color in the image, but in the image, have at least 50%