# Color Space and color Ranges for Efficient Color detection

Tags: java, android, colors

I am making an app for solving Rubik's cube. For standard rubik's cube there are mainly 6 colors (Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,White,Blue).

In our app we want to have functionality to automatically detecting colors and filling this detected colors in our cube. I have looked through and applied **"RGB and HSV"** color space based color detection Algorithms.

RGB was pretty bad and HSV was quite good comparing to RGB. In both of these algorithms we have Ranges(for RGB Space we have ranges of RGB values and same for HSV) through which we were deciding colors.for deciding these ranges i have gone through these references .

1. [Java colour detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178978/java-colour-detection)
2. [HSV Color ranges table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357732/hsv-color-ranges-table)

Now, I want to go for **YCbCr and CIELAB color space**,I am able to convert **RGB Color space to YCbCr and CIELAB Color space**, but for deciding colors through **LAB and YCbCr Values** i need range by which i can decide the colors. I have gone through many online resources but could not find the range for these values by which i can decide colors. Can anyone share these ranges?