# Can I sort any given point on the HSV color space to a limited number of base colors, i.e. 12 or 16 that have clear names?

Tags: colors, converters, hsv

I want a software to be able to convert a given "pipetted" input color from a photography with a HSV-representation into a human-readable descriptor of a base color. So no matter which combination of HSV-values I pick from a color wheel, it would be converted to the closest "neighbor" of a given, limited number of base colors.

[image: An example for a 12-base-color-wheel.]

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357732/hsv-color-ranges-table?rq=1) is a similar question, because it also ennumerated base colors?

Comment: It is possible that the answer is much easier than I though. Given I set Saturation and Value to "100", my Hue should always have a base color, right?

Comment: Colour wheels usually show (in outer wheel) only hue (so independent to L (or V) and S), so just classify on angles of H

Comment: Note: you are using the "wrong" colour wheel (for most visual arts, and science uses). Blue and yellows are complementary values. But good for colour picking (red hues are the most important and distinguishable colours)